# MongoDB: "Unrecognized option: systemLog"

Tags: mongodb

guys.

I have a problem with the configuration files of MongoDB. It seem that use the YAML syntax.

I follow the instruction on the official website. I read something about YAML and I tried to figure out what is wrong, but I don't got any result.This is the mongod.conf file

```
# mongod.conf

systemLog:
  verbosity=5
  traceAllExceptions=true
  path="/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
  destination=file
  timeStampFormat=iso8601-utc
  pidFilePath="/run/mongod.pid"

net:
  port=[8040,8041,8042]
  wiredObjectCheck=true
  ssl.mode=preferSSL
  ssl.PEMKeyFile="/var/lib/mongodb/mongo.pem"
  serviceExecutor=adaptive

storage:
  dbPath="/home/juny/nodeBox/data/db"

operationProfiling.mode=slowOp
```

It's suppose to work well, when you execute the following command:

```
service mongod start
```

But when you type following command:

```
service mongod status
```

The terminal display this:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-05-25 20:12:24 AST; 2min 21s ago
 Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 5093 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)
Main PID: 5093 (code=exited, status=2)

May 25 20:12:24 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
May 25 20:12:24 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
May 25 20:12:24 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 25 20:12:24 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I type the following command

```
sudo mongod --config=/etc/mongod.conf
```

and this is the result

```
Unrecognized option: systemLog
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

Comment: The separator in YAML should be a `:` rather than `=` (for all items, including sub-items like `verbosity`). For an example config file see: [`mongodb.conf`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/mongod.conf). I'd recommend starting with a simple config file and adding one option at a time to help isolate any syntax errors. Your `net.port` setting is incorrect: it should be a single port that this `mongod` is accepting connections on. The `wiredObjectCheck` is also invalid but not needed (this should be `wireObjectCheck`, which defaults to `true`).

Comment: I would also be cautious on setting options like  `verbosity=5` and `traceAllExceptions`, as this will generate a lot of debug detail that generally isn't useful unless you are troubleshooting at a server source code level. Most issues can be diagnosed at the default log level. I would start with the default settings and increase detail by component using [`db.setLogLevel()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/).

Comment: Ok. thank for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I found the error. The configuration file its must be look like the same above, but changing the equal symbol '=' by a colon ':'. Also, some words in the configuration are wrong. I had to verify the manual to realize the failure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (with mongo v4.2) I had to replace all spaces indent with tabs.

P.S. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/ says:

> YAML does not support tab characters for indentation: use spaces instead.

It looks that spaces are OK,
but anyways,  the problem was with whitespace (non-printable characters).